# ServiceFabric service restarting (apparently) without reason

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a ServiceFabric application with a service that gets restarted a few times a day apparently without reasons.
Actually I've noticed that it happens when it under heavy load.

Could it be that it is related to the balancer that detects the heavy load and tries to rebalance the nodes?

How can I ensure that my application doesn't get restarted? Is it enough to set the `DefaultMoveCost` to `High` (or is there a higher level)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to find out why your service gets moved, make sure you've configured [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-overview).

Also, see if your service can be run using multiple instances, so you can afford to lose one. This also helps remaining available during service upgrades.

Influencing cluster balancing is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-balancing).

You can't guarantee your service stays in place using [MoveCost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-movement-cost). (High is the highest level.)

> Setting your move cost to High does not guarantee that the replica
>   stays in one place.